# Delete all objects in entity when iOS app is closed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have some problem with *Core Data* in **Swift**.
Here is my simple model:

[image: model]

I fetch data from Region and Districts into two `UITableViews`. It's working fine, but after closing app `UITableView` with Districts becomes empty. I don't save context. Transient option is disabled. Regions show normal.

Fetch code looks like this:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Districts> = Districts.fetchRequest()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "distToReg.name == %@", self.RegionNameChoose)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

do {
    let searchResults = try CoreDataManager.instance.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
    self.count = searchResults.count

    for result1 in searchResults {
        self.result.append(result1.name!)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error with request: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: By "closing" you mean sending it to background or killing?

Comment: Killing or new compilation

Comment: Are you saving your managed object context when the app is backgrounded?

Comment: No, i don't. I nothing change in entities, only show data in UITableView. But after closing app manually or installing update second UITableView is empty (first UITableView looks normal).

Comment: There is no problem if i background app and return or unwind ViewController and return.

Comment: If you never save context then it never gets persisted to the store, so it's gone the next time the app starts up.

Comment: I added saving context in viewDidDisappear of second UITableView and it's working, but i don't understand why do i need to save context after fetch (not add or change data) and why does it happen in second UITableView only?

Comment: When you're fetching you see results, but when you close the app and return and perform the same result, you get no results? If you're creating entities and relationships in the same context where you are later fetching, there is no need to save, because the context maintains everything in memory. It sounds like the save is not actually successful. Or maybe your Core Data stack is more complicated, and you're only saving at one context level, and not the parent level, all the way back to the persistent store. Can you share your save code?

Comment: I added save context after each creating value of second entity. And it's work too. I thought enough to save after adding all objects. It's wrong apparently. Thank you all for the help. The understanding started to come.